# How to restore windows boot

Tags: windows-10, boot

I reset my boot manager, easyBCD warn me that I should add boot options and I add drive C option. So I was wrong and now I have fully functional and installed Windows 10, but I just can't boot in. So there is the question, in bios (Asus) I have option: add new boot, and possibility to add boot path, I found some .efi files like bootmgfw.efi fbx64.efi bootx64.efi.

Any chances that this files are not corrupted and I can booting with them?

Or there is no chance and I just need to make another windows image and install/repair it? 
And now I have Ubuntu live USB by my hands, so maybe I have another options? 
I don't need any data.

Comment: You just need to restore the boot loader. Nothing is needed in the BIOS. It is automatic. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7-8-81-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

Comment: @Appleoddity could I do that process with Ubuntu live USB? I assume I need to burn windows image for this

Comment: It’s just as easy to make a windows USB so I would recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add the path to `bootmgfw.efi` as the boot option. This is the default Windows 10 Boot Manager file for EFI systems. `bootx64.efi` (or `bkpbootx64.efi`) is a copy of `bootmgfw.efi` and is used as the fallback boot manager if anything were to happen to the original one.

The path **should** (you have to check for your case, not blindly copy/paste) be something like the following:

`/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` or `/boot/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` (most probably the first if no other OS has been installed on the system before that).

And yes, those files are most likely to be safe and not corrupted.

**Edit:**

As you reply that using the path to the boot manager does **not** work, I can only suggest you to either repair by using a recovery windows image (as stated in comments by @Appleoddity), or just install your Windows again from scratch, since you don't need any data.

Comment: When I try to use bootmgfw.efi file as a path for boot, and use it screen go black for a few seconds and that's all I'm staying in bios.

Comment: This https://imgur.com/gallery/T9dW5tp

Comment: Have you tried `bootmgr.efi`?

Comment: yep, same result. Thx for help anyway!